# Simplify a Boolean Expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have to simplify this w′x′y′z + wx'yz' + w'xyz'

I keep getting different answers depending on whether I start on the left or the right of the expression

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Mary

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! It would be good if you could provide your two different workings so that we can see which step has a problem!

Comment: Also have you tried plotting a truth table, or [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), for both the original expression and your answers to see if they are equivalent?

Comment: Thanks to all, I actually figured it out using the truth table and Karnaugh map as suggested

Answer (score 0):

That term is already in its minimal form, because each of the disjuncts is a prime implicant.